# Remove Keyboard after clicking URL from InlineKeyboardButton

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm creating a wrapper for /commands in python

I created an InlineKeyboardButton with a URL to chat the bot in private.  I want the button to remove or disappear, just not show after the user clicks the url button.

I have used the generic wrapper from the telegram tutorials.

However, I am a "newb" :) Always trying to learn something new I can share.

In this case, I've become stuck.

Unlike callback_data where data can be sent to another button to edit the message. The URL doesn't send anything. I just want the button to vanish or the best alternative hide or something.

Any Ideas??

what direction to move in :)

I have looked into ReplyKeyboardRemove and OneTimeKeyboard but either my syntax is off or It isn't possible with a URL button

````
def myrestricted(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(bot, update):
        user = update.message.from_user.username
        if update.message.chat.type != "private" :
            group = update.message.chat.id
            if user not in ADMIN_ONLY:
                button = [InlineKeyboardButton("7heUnknown_Bot", url='t.me/7heUnknown_Bot',],
                bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Please click the button below to talk with me privately")
                return
        return func(bot, update)
    return wrapped```

When the user clicks on the URL button I want the button to disappear.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

`InlineKeyboardButton` with a `URL` only displays the button for users to open a link. As far as I know, there's no *event* in Telegram's API that can be fired when the user actually *opens* the link (or even *clicks* on the button!)

Comment: Thanks, man! Appreciate your input! I have tried and tried and what you said makes sense. There is nothing being sent back to the bot so no way to remove.

I'll stop banging my head!

Much much appreciation.

Comment: @TheVoice Happy to help